# incorrect result when filtering by association

Tags: mysql

I have a docket, which has many entries. I want only dockets, where none of the associating entries contains the text "PENDING". For example, if docket A has 10 entries, and one of those entries' docket_type varchar field contains the word "PENDING" anywhere, then I don't want that docket.

This is my solution:

```
SELECT * FROM dockets
INNER JOIN entries 
ON entries.docket_id = docket.id 
WHERE (docket_type NOT LIKE '%PENDING%')
```

The problem is, while it does not retrieve entries that contain that text, it still retrieves the associating dockets, when those dockets contain other entries that do not contain that text. I don't want to retrieve the docket if one of its entries contains this text in docket_type.

How could I fix this?

Comment: Do you want to keep the `entries` (without "pending") in the `SELECT` list?

Comment: @ypercube yes but if an entry does have "pending", I don't want the docket either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need one more join (a `LEFT` join with `IS NULL` check) or a `NOT EXISTS` subquery and to move the condition (reversed!) there:

```
SELECT * FROM dockets
INNER JOIN entries 
ON entries.docket_id = docket.id 
WHERE NOT EXISTS
      ( SELECT 1
        FROM entries AS e
        WHERE e.docket_id = docket.id 
          AND e.docket_type LIKE '%PENDING%'
      ) ;
```

Comment: Can I get a brief explanation of why you use the number 1 in "SELECT 1"?

Comment: You can use whatever you like. People often use `SELECT *` or `SELECT 1` or `SELECT NULL` in exists and not exists subqueries. The exists means that the subquery returns a boolean value, either true or false, dependent on when the subquery has **rows**. So, the select list doesn't really matter.